# What is a foolproof way to consistently size a bitmap across all screens

Tags: android, image, bitmap

My Android app has rulers that need to measure accurately on all screens, no matter what size or density. The rulers are drawable resources that I set to an image view via `BitmapFactory`.

My initial approach has been to set the bitmaps to an image view whose relative `layout_width` is set to a fixed 50mm (the precise width of the underlying png's) and whose scale type is `FIT_CENTER`.

Because I have found Android'd pre-scaling to be quite thwarting, I've tried to disable this processes by declaring `android:anyDensity="true"` in the manifest in conjunction with using the `BitmapFactory` option `inScaled = "false"`.

The ruler bitmaps I'm using are 320dpi pngs that all measure 50mm wide. My thought was to provide a high resolution image that could easily scale down nicely to the exact needed width on lower density screens.

The above method has worked successfully across almost all beta-tested devices. But on the HTC Evo 4G, the rulers appear too large. The latter device, running Android 2.3.5, is the only reported fail so far.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same issue with Android 2.3.5 on my devices, fixed by rescaling all images manually. My images are set into ImageView at runtime, so it is not a problem for me to rescale image before.

```
byte[] icon = Icon.getIcon(mContext.getFilesDir());
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(icon, 0, icon.length);
        int width = LicenseDialog.convertDpToPx(mContext, 48);
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, width, width, true).compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
        icon = stream.toByteArray();
```